# Open app when push is received

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am writing an Android+iOS app using Cordova/PhoneGap+Ionic2 and I would like to open the app when a push notification is received.

If the app is is the background how can I open it upon receipt of the push? I would like this to happen without the user pressing a button - much like Skype does when you receive an incoming call.

Here is my current handler for the push notifications:

```
// Handle received Push
this.push.rx.notification().subscribe((msg) => {
    alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
});
```

This works, but the alert action not take occur until AFTER the user clicks the received notification. I would like to bring the user in to the app automatically, and then present them with my own interface to the received notification.

I looked at [How to bring a Cordova Android application to foreground or start and bring to foreground once connected (and turn screen on) programmatically on GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233799/how-to-bring-a-cordova-android-application-to-foreground-or-start-and-bring-to-f) and https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app - but I still do not have any event that occurs BEFORE the user clicks on the notification in which to call this plugin and therefore cannot use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need go native, even if there is several plugins that allow to handled very good the GCM / FCM flow, most of this (At least the ones that I trust) don't handled what you want.

In Android you could use the [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and here decide if show or not the notification, and after that decide if launch the App Intent or not.

In iOS you could use the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method and decide what to do in there.

In both case I believe that show the app without any user action could be considered as bad UX experience (Even if possible). For example, for iOS they never mention this options in its [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html) for Handling App State Transitions

Comment: Thank you for pointing out those events, they sound like what I am looking for and I will look into them. Re: bad UX, I would tend to agree that it seems to be intrusive, but then I think about Skype which appears to do exactly the same thing. Like Skype, my intention would not be to just open the app upon push, but instead to show a screen which allows them to choose what action to take next. Hopefully this would not be intrusive, and seems possible considering that Skype does it.